# Multiple iterables as arguments in python multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have 3 dimensional dataset `(100,64,3000)`, and i am finding features using multiprocessing. I am doing multiprocessing across channel. Such as each process cover 8 channels out of 64. 
Here is my code

```
import numpy as np
import time
from multiprocessing import Process,current_process,Pool

sub=1
def cal_feature(ch):
    data=np.load('data_{}.npy'.format(sub))
    return np.mean(data[:,ch:ch+8,:],-1)


# multiprocessing
if __name__ == '__main__':

    start = time.time()
    ch=[i for i in range(0,64,8)]
    with Pool(8) as p:
        result = p.map(cal_feature,(ch) )
    print(time.time()-start)
```

You can create dummy data this way.

```
import numpy as np
np.save('data_1', np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(100, 64, 3000)))
np.save('data_2', np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(100, 64, 3000)))
np.save('data_3', np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(100, 64, 3000)))
np.save('data_4', np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(100, 64, 3000)))
```

In my code i have to define which data has to be picked manually `sub=1`. What I want to modify the above code such that it pick `sub =1` and then find feature for all channels in a multiprocess way. When its done it move to subject 2 and so on.

EDIT

```
ind_result=[result[i:i+8] for i in range(0,(len(sub)*8),8)]
for i,j in zip(sub,ind_result):
    np.save('subject_0_{}'.format(i),np.concatenate((j),1)   )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're facing a common limitation of the `multiprocessing`, that is that `pool.map` only accepts one argument iterable.

You can work around that by packing `ch` and `sub` into a tuple, and build the argument iterable with `itertools.product` ([reference here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)). You can then unpack the two arguments inside the `cal_feature` function.

```py
import numpy as np
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool
from itertools import product

def cal_feature(param):
    sub, ch = param
    data=np.load('data_{}.npy'.format(sub))
    return np.mean(data[:,ch:ch+8,:],-1)


# multiprocessing
if __name__ == '__main__':

    start = time.time()
    ch=[i for i in range(0,64,8)]
    sub = [1, 2, 3, 4]

    # here's the magic
    param_list = product(sub, ch)
    print list(param_list)
    # [(1, 0), (1, 8), (1, 16), (1, 24), (1, 32), (1, 40), (1, 48), 
    # (1, 56), (2, 0), (2, 8), (2, 16), (2, 24), (2, 32), (2, 40), 
    # (2, 48), (2, 56), (3, 0), (3, 8), (3, 16), (3, 24), (3, 32), 
    # (3, 40), (3, 48), (3, 56), (4, 0), (4, 8), (4, 16), (4, 24), 
    # (4, 32), (4, 40), (4, 48), (4, 56)]

    p = Pool(8)
    result = p.map(cal_feature,param_list )
    p.close()
    print(time.time()-start)
    # 0.0117809772491
```

Comment: btw is there any other way to seprate the output of each subject from result variable. I did this     ind_result=[result[i:i+8] for i in range(0,(len(sub)*8),8)]
    for i,j in zip(sub,ind_result):
        np.save('subject_0_{}'.format(i),np.concatenate((j),1)   )

Answer (score 1):

There are some limitations for `Pool`, I tried some methods, and recommend this way:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool
from itertools import product
from functools import partial


def cal_feature(sub, ch):
    return sub, ch


ch = [i for i in range(0, 16, 8)]
sub_list = [1, 2, 3]


def pool_helper(f, args):
    return f(*args)


with Pool(8) as p:
    result = p.map(partial(pool_helper, cal_feature), product(sub_list, ch))

print(result)
# output is [(1, 0), (1, 8), (2, 0), (2, 8), (3, 0), (3, 8)]
```

We don't need change original `cal_feature`, and `pool_helper` can be used for any function which accepts positional params.